# Best way to import a svn repo to git that has trunk, tags, branches and releases

Tags: git-svn

I run a project on [sourceforge](http://sf.net) called [mqmanager.NET](http://www.sf.net/mqmanager) that I inherited from the original author. Long story short I want to migrate this, and the rest of, my sourceforge projects to github. The problem here is that the typical import process assumes you have trunk, tags, and branches. I have these plus a **releases** folder. The particular command I am currently using is:

```
git.exe svn clone "https://mqmanager.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mqmanager"  "C:\src\mqmanager" -T trunk -b branches -t tags
```

Now, I'm mainly concerned by trunk and releases, but I'd like to keep everything. Is there another version of the command I should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [TFM](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_commands):

> You can specify more
>                  than one --tags and/or --branches options, in case your
>                  Subversion repository places tags or branches under multiple
>                  paths.

If releases should be turned into git tags, then you could say

```
git svn clone <url> <local> -T trunk -b branches -t tags -t releases
```